# Pumping lemma: the set of strings of 0s and 1s such that when interpreted as an integer, that integer is prime

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma, number-theory

In the section of my textbook covering the pumping lemma, there are practice questions asking us to prove a given language is not regular.

I have not been able to solve this one:

> The set of strings of 0s and 1s, beginning with a 1, and interpreted
>   as an integer, that integer is prime.

My attempt:

Assume to the contrary that the language is regular. Let $p$ be the pumping length given by the pumping lemma. Let $s = 101$. The pumping lemma guarantees s can be broken into 3 substrings, x, y, z such that $|xy| \leq p$ and $y \neq \epsilon$....

Obviously this is where it breaks down, because I haven't given a string that is of at least length $p$ (ie $s = 10^p1$).

Comment: [Crosspost on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765304/3330) -- please don't do that. It's rude on people that waste their time on writing redundant answer.s

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are missing is Fermat's Little Theorem: If $p$ is a prime and $p$ does not divide $a$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p$.

I'll give an example application in base 10. Let's assume that 2039 is the prime to which the pumping lemma is applied and the decomposition is 2 03 9. That is the pumping lemma would imply that all strings of the form $2(03)^n9$ denote prime numbers. At least it is true for $n\in\{0,1,2\}$. But without further calculation I know that it fails for $n=28$: The number $N=2030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303039$ is divisible by $29$, which is the number at $n=0$. To see this, observe that 
$N = 20\cdot 100^{28} + \sum\limits_{0\leq i< 28}30\cdot 100^i + 9
= 20\cdot 100^{28} + 30\cdot\frac{100^{28}-1}{100-1} + 9$ and apply Fermat's theorem. 
Here, we also use that $29$ does not divide $100-1$.

I hope from this you are able to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show that this language isn’t regular is to use the following theorem:

> Let $L$ be a regular language over $\Sigma$, and let $c_n = |L \cap \Sigma^n|$. There exists a modulus $m \geq 1$ such that for all $0 \leq r < m$ there exist real $C,\lambda \geq 0$ and integer $k \geq 0$ such that the following asymptotic estimate holds for $n \equiv r \pmod{m}$:
>   $$ c_n \sim Cn^k \lambda^n. $$

In your case, $c_n$ is the number of primes between $2^{n-1}$ and $2^n-1$. According to the prime number theorem, the number of primes up to $2^n$ is asymptotic to $2^n/n \log 2$, and so
$$
c_n \sim \frac{1}{\log 2} \left( \frac{2^n}{n} - \frac{2^{n-1}}{n-1} \right) \sim \frac{1}{2\log 2} \frac{2^n}{n}.
$$
This contradicts the theorem above.

Comment: Would you mind giving me a reference for this theorem, @Yuval Filmus ?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#The_number_of_words_in_a_regular_language), which cites Theorem V.3 of Flajolet and Sedgewick.